# How to get 100 waves on G10?

Tags: gemcraft-labyrinth

I'm trying to get the challenge amulet on field G10.  Normally, this field has 12 waves; the challenge is to clear 100.  How can I force it to spawn 100 waves?  Is it only possible with the premium version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a go at it playing 4x27 wave in a row and no luck either so to complete this you need to have the Premium Edition and set number of waves to Endurance.

Comment: I just tested, and unfortunately, it didn't work.  I'm guessing the premium version (with unlimited waves) is the only way to get it.

Comment: that sucks, was hoping just running it a couple of times would do it since it didn't specify it had to be in one go and some of the other challenge specify it